# How to stop The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()

Tags: javascript

I made website if the user client the play button the video will play smoothly but when the video plays for sec then it stops playing.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var ppbutton = document.getElementById("vidbutton");
    ppbutton.addEventListener("click", playPause);
    myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");
    function playPause() {
        if (myVideo.paused) {
            myVideo.play();
            ppbutton.innerHTML = "Pause";
            }
        else  {
            myVideo.pause();
            ppbutton.innerHTML = "Play";
            }
    }
});
```

But that causes the error: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().` Coming up everytime but the video plays an stop brings up the error message again everytime clicking on the play button.